# Using snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates: to pass UIImage to view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimage, screenshot

I'm using Swift with Xcode 6 Beta 6. I want my app to take a screenshot with snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates: right before performing a segue to another view controller. This screenshot is then to be passed as a UIImage so that it can be used as a background.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The snapshot methods return a view, not an image - the view contains a specialised layer that performs the snapshotting.

If you're just using it as a background, there's no need to bother with an image - simply use the snapshot view as the background view.

Comment: Thanks, although I have a bit of a problem. I have the first view controller that plays the game, and when this game ends it takes a snapshot and passes it to the second vc. In the second vc, I have a visual effect view with blur. I replace the enclosed view with the snapshot from the first view controller to give a cool effect. This works for a moment, while the segue is happening (present modally), but once the vc is fully displayed, the background changes to a solid gray colour. What is happening??

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing some of your code. All of this information should have been in your question really.